# how to make ios app as a plugin

Tags: ios

I have a small app which displays different hot offers in malls, restaurents  and their  details around the user location. So I have to install this app in some other applications as a plugin. Is it possible in IOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well No and Yes, You as the developer of this app can not still your app in other apps as and plugin.

You might offer other developers to download you app and a framework and us it in there apps.